# Is there a way to solve a poly() by declaring the variable?

Tags: scilab

I'm new with the scilab synthax,  and I want to know if there is a way to
declare a poly, like p = 3x + 2, and use something like p(5) to get 17 as an answer. The reason to do so is that the poly synthax is a lot easier than defining the same expression over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scilab polynom can be define with special function [poly](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/poly.html). In your case, this command will look like this:

```
x=poly(0,"x"); 
p = 3*x+2
```

for obtain value in point need use function [horner](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/horner.html):

```
horner(p,5)
```

and we get

```
 ans  =

    17.
```